# what is the difference between iphone device UDID , iphone device ID and iphone device Token?

Tags: iphone

what is the difference between iphone device UDID , iphone device ID and iphone device Token ??

Normally iphone device token is used when we are using apple push notification service.

But my goal is to just identify unique iphone device ? So which of the above 3 is unique for iphone device ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The device ID and UDID are different names for the same thing. The device token is used for a server to send notifications to that device using Apple's Push Notification service - it lets the APN server know which device you're talking about, but doesn't have any meaning outside that context.