# Is the device token as unique as the device ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, devicetoken

If we reset an iPhone, the device ID remains the same. Is it the same for the device token?

Comment: Have a look at [this question on SO][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726107/what-is-the-difference-between-iphone-device-udid-iphone-device-id-and-iphone-d

Comment: generally, UDID shouldn't be used for any purpose, so that's when token comes in handy.

Comment: but if somebody reset it's iPhone, will the device token change ? Or is it generated by apple from the UDID ?

Comment: I've never considered it, but if it is the same as UDID, than it probably shouldn't change.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the device token available to methods such as

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

If this is the case, then no, the device token **can** and **will change**.

Quoted from Apples [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2)

> By requesting the device token and passing it to the provider every time your application launches, you help to ensure that the provider has the current token for the device. If a user restores a backup to a device other than the one that the backup was created for (for example, the user migrates data to a new device), he or she must launch the application at least once for it to receive notifications again. If the user restores backup data to a new device or reinstalls the operating system, the device token changes. Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it

I can also verify this behaviour as I use [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) as my notification provider and even though I have only ever used a single test device so far, there are numerous device tokens registered with my account.

Comment: "never cache a device token and give that to your provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it", the thing is, where do you get the device token. you have to store it locally and check whether the token is different from the original one (Rayswenderich use this method in his tutorial.

Comment: That quote is taken directly from Apple's Local and Push Notification Programming Guide. There's absolutely no need to cache the token; you simply ask Apple for it on each launch of your app, and then send that onto your push provider.

Answer (score 1):

Device token is unique id but will be change.